# Is the a way to use a complex type as an input column for a spark ml transformer

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib

I'm trying to use a Vector from inside a struct as the input column to a spark mllib transform. Like this ...

```scala
import org.apache.spark.ml.linalg._
case class State(id: String, features: Vector)
val ds  = Seq[(State,State)]().toDS
ds.printSchema()
```

```
root
|-- _1: struct (nullable = true)
|    |-- id: string (nullable = true)
|    |-- features: vector (nullable = true)
|-- _2: struct (nullable = true)
|    |-- id: string (nullable = true)
|    |-- features: vector (nullable = true)
```

But cannot pass `_1.features` as the input column to a transformer...

```scala
val pca = new PCA().
setInputCol("_1.features").
setOutputCol("output").
setK(3).
fit(ds)
```

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Field "_1.features" does not exist.
Available fields: _1, _2
  at org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(StructType.scala:274)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(StructType.scala:274)
  at scala.collection.MapLike$class.getOrElse(MapLike.scala:128)
  at scala.collection.AbstractMap.getOrElse(Map.scala:59)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType.apply(StructType.scala:273)
  at org.apache.spark.ml.util.SchemaUtils$.checkColumnType(SchemaUtils.scala:41)
  at org.apache.spark.ml.feature.PCAParams$class.validateAndTransformSchema(PCA.scala:56)
  at org.apache.spark.ml.feature.PCA.validateAndTransformSchema(PCA.scala:70)
  at org.apache.spark.ml.feature.PCA.transformSchema(PCA.scala:105)
  at org.apache.spark.ml.PipelineStage.transformSchema(Pipeline.scala:74)
  at org.apache.spark.ml.feature.PCA.fit(PCA.scala:94)
```

Short of renaming the field, does anyone know a work around for this problem?

Answer (score 0):

An easy workaround would be to select only the part of your dataset that you need since Spark ML seems to have issues with nested columns.

e.g. The following should work:

```
val dsFeatures = ds.select("_1.id", "_1.features")
val pca = new PCA().setInputCol("features").setOutputCol("output").setK(3).fit(dsFeatures)
```

Or at least fail for different reasons! :)

Comment: Thanks for this @Gevorg. Unfortunately, I need to keep the other columns for subsequent processing.

Comment: maybe you could (as a workaround of course) duplicate the features with `.withColumn("features1", $"_1.features")`